# How do I print the first occurence of a string after a special character in Hive using reg_extract or split?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am having a deep dilemma in hive. My data set in Hive looks like this:

```
##214628##564#7576#7876

#12771#242###256823

###3264###7236473####3
```

In each instance, I want to print only the first string after the #. So the output should be something like this:

```
214628

12771

3264
```

I tried using the reg_extract function, but alas I am getting only NULL values. Since hive doesn't support reg_substr, the following synatax doesn't work:

```
to_number(trim(regexp_substr(col_name,'[^#]+',1,1)))
```

Any suggestions are wecome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regexp_replace and then substr combination.

First remove all multiple occurrences of # from the string using `regexp_replace()`.

```
regexp_replace(col,'#+','#') -- for data '#####123##' this will produce '#123#'
```

Then remove first # using substr. And then use instr to fetch everything starting from first till #.

```
substr(substr(str,2),1, instr(substr(str,2),'#')-1)  this will produce '123'
```

You can see whole sql below.

```
select  substr(substr(str,2),1, instr(substr(str,2),'#')-1) as result
from (
SELECT regexp_replace('#####123##','#+','#') as str) a
```

I assumed you always have # in the beginning. if you just add `if left(str,1)='#'...` and handle according to the data.

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution! I actually used: 

select REGEXP_EXTRACT('###23286####24739#####','[^#]+',0);

but your solution seems more foolproof so i think i will go with that